# Is “function” a JavaScript type?

Tags: javascript

Is "function" a JavaScript type?

For example:

```js
console.log(typeof alert) // returns function
```

Which suggests that "function" is indeed a type

However, in [this](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values) ECMAscript documentation it says:

> The ECMAScript language types are Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Symbol, Number, BigInt, and Object”.

Could someone explain this to me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Function is also an object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox
so, why here is information about nine types (including "function")?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: @Peter That MDN page does not list `Function` as a separate ECMAScript type - that page says it's a "structural type" which is not the same thing as a fundamental ECMAScript type.

Comment: Same reason Array isn’t. They’re not fundament types

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The behaviour of the `typeof` operator is documented in section 12.5.5](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator), which has a table that answers your question.

It says (paraphrased):

- Given the expression `typeof val`:

  - When `val` is an `Object` which implements the `[[Call]]` interface then `typeof` returns the string `'function'`
  - When `val` is an `Object` which does *not* implement `[[Call]]` then `typeof` returns the string `'object'`.

Thus, `function` is not a separate ECMAScript type, but is actually a specialization of the `Object`-type.

---

Do note that the information in the ECMAScript specification is very technical and narrowly specific and is intended primarily for implementors of ECMAScript engines and tooling - and while it is useful for developers using JS as a language, it is not intended to be beginner-friendly or serve as an introduction to the language - or to explain fundamentals.

---

The precise definition of a "function object" [is explained in 6.1.7.2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#function-object).